# AWS Find all groups/users that have access to a specific role

Tags: amazon-iam

If I have a role named `OperationAdmins` which grants the `AdministratorAccess` Policy to anyone that assumes the role, how can I find a list of all users or groups that can assume the `OperationAdmins` role?

Comment: Isn't role is supposed to give permissions to users or groups? Do you want to know the users or group to which this role has been assigned?

Comment: Can assume or are assuming? If it's can, it's whoever is mentioned in the allow statements in the trust relationship of the role being assumed. What are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you an example, and you can customize it to fit your own needs. You can use the IAM policy simulator API to achieve this.

```py
import boto3

iamc = boto3.client('iam')
iamr = boto3.resource('iam')
iam_paginator = iamc.get_paginator('list_users')
iam_page_iterator = iam_paginator.paginate()

operation_admins_iam_role = iamr.Role('OperationAdmins')
operation_admins_iam_role_arn = operation_admins_iam_role.arn

for page in iam_page_iterator:
    users = page['Users']
    for user in users:
        user_arn = user['Arn']
        resp = iamc.simulate_principal_policy(
            PolicySourceArn=user_arn,
            ActionNames=['sts:AssumeRole'],
            ResourceArns=[operation_admins_iam_role_arn]
        )
        decision = resp['EvaluationResults'][0]['EvalDecision']
        print(user_arn, decision)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two sides to trust.

1. The identity asking to assume
2. The identity allowing the assume

(Asker) Users/Groups can have permissions. The important one being `sts:AssumeRole`.

(Allowing) In your case `OperationAdmins` role. They will have a trust relationship which defines who is allowed to assume itself.

**Read more:** https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-trust-policies-with-iam-roles/

This trust relationship **Allow anyone** in account 111122223333 and with permissions `sts:AssumeRole` to assume it.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root" 
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

This trust relationship **Allow user LiJuan** if he has `sts:AssumeRole` permissions.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/LiJuan"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```